# Use pip to Install to a different interpreter

Tags: python, windows, pip

I downloaded Python2.7 a while ago to my C:\ directory. After that I downloaded pip to install packages. After that I installed the Anaconda interpreter to a different directory within my user. I prefer to use the Anaconda interpreter but every time I install a package with pip it is put in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages. Is there any way I can change the install command with pip or some pip config file so that it installs packages to C:\path_to_anaconda_interpreter_in_user\Lib\site-packages?

Comment: You may want to use Anaconda\s package manager `conda` instead of `pip`, see http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/pkgs.html

Comment: I'm trying to install lesser known packages called Scikits, and the conda command does not seem to be able to fetch them

Comment: A solution using `virtualenv` would be acceptable?

Comment: Modify `PATH` to prefer Anaconda's pip.exe instead of the one in `C:\Python27\Scripts`.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is create a symbolic link.

Or in your case, on windows, a shortcut.

So in your case : `C:\path_to_anaconda_interpreter_in_user\Lib\site-packages` would be a shortcut leading to `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`

(right click python27/lib/site-packages, click 'create shortcut' and move it into your anaconda lib directory)

**Edit :**

See Eryksun's comment below

Comment: It would be better to create a virtualenv using the `--python` flag pointing to the Anaconda Python interpreter.

Comment: Windows shortcuts are implemented by the shell and do not work like filesystem symbolic links. To create a directory symbolic link, use cmd's built-in command `mklink /d link target`. This requires `SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege`. An elevated administrator has this privilege, and it can also be manually added to a standard user account using secpol.msc.

Comment: I deleted my C\:Python27 interpreter and I already have an environment variable set to my Anaconda\Scripts which means I should be running the pip inside of that directory but instead of installing it into the Anaconda\Lib\site-packages directory, it is putting them in AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\76\b6\0c\cef0b6fcd60a8af1502419fe944e7a003bb47168587075a9e3. Conda does not recognize the packages I am trying to install. eryksun, if you could send me a link to a more detailed explanation of what you are talking about, that would help